# dtale - Highlight Outliers only flashing up once, then colors vanish

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, eda

I am using dtale (https://pypi.org/project/dtale/) for the visualization of my pandas data frames in jupyter-notebook on Ubuntu (browser is Chrome). When I press the option "Highlight" and then "Highlight Outliers" the colors flash up once in my data frame, but vanish immediately after. I get no error message, nor can I save or export the highlighted data frame. The columns are correctly marked with a star, stating how many outliers there are for each column.
I sadly cannot share the data I used as it contains sensible information.

Is there any way to keep the highlighting of the outliers? Could someone recreate this behavior?

dtale version: 2.9.0
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Google Chrome Version 107.0.5304.110
Jupyter-Notebook 6.4.12

Code used in jupyter notebook:
import dtale
dtale.show(df)